# Generating id for Guid-keyed IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I have modified the default MVC5 template to, rather use than `string`/`nvarchar`-keyed users, to use `Guid`s/`uniqueidentifier`s. My solution was similar to the one discussed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx

I changed the type parameters where applicable, but my first user was generated with an id of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. The second user could not be created because its primary key conflicted with that of the first.

I then changed the applicable type parameters from `Guid` to `int`, and then it worked, with user ids starting at 1 and incrementing.

So how do I get it to work with `Guid`?

I just need to hook in somewhere and assign each newly created user a new Guid. Where is the best place to do this? I thought maybe in the ApplicationUser (implements IdentityUser<Guid, ...>) constructor, but I was unsure.

Comment: You need to make sure the Guid field is marked as an Identity field, otherwise EF won't auto-generate the ID. That's easy to do with database-first, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is for Code-First.

Comment: Looks like you'd use these annotations: `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: A Guid is not automatically generated for you. You need to generate it yourself, otherwise it would have it's default value, which is all zeros.

Comment: Yes, I can see this, but when and where should I do it?

Comment: You would need to address me with an `@` symbol. That way I get notified of your response. ;) You should either invoke a database script `NEWID()` or generate a guid in your data layer code with `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that Tieson T's comment represented the correct answer, but it was posted as a comment, rather than an answer, so I'll reproduce my specific solution here. In my `ApplicationUser` class (implements `IdentityUser`), I overrode the `Id` property and added the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOptionAttribute` attributes. My applicationUser class thus looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override Guid Id
    {
        get { return base.Id; }
        set { base.Id = value; }
    }
    ...
}
```